# How to use ansible api(by python) to get Windows host info?

Tags: ansible-2.x

I know how to use ansible to connect to Windows hosts. And I also can get some info by setup module. But now I want to get info through the ansible api. It's not hard to do this if the host is a Linux system, but I don't know how to do that if the host is a Windows system.

Answer (score 0):

ok,I know how to do that.There is a option named connection,this option's default value is 'ssh',you can change it to 'winrm',then you can use the api to manage windows host